# jQuery Form to Wizard, hiding a certain step

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]I have this form, I want to hide one of the fieldset when the onchange event is triggered. I have one select tag inside the first fieldset. When I select fieldset 2 from the dropdown list the second fieldset must be removed.

```
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset class="sectionwrap">
        <select id="hide">
            <option value="1">fieldset 2</option>
            <option value="2">fieldset 3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id ="second" class="sectionwrap">content</fieldset>

    <fieldset id="third" class="sectionwrap">content</fieldset>
</form>
```

I have this Jquery script. but the Step number on top of the form wizard is not removed, only the contents were removed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hide').on('change', function() {
        var hid = $('#hide').val();
        if (hid == "1") {
            $('#form1').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('#form1').css("display","none"); here you have to use id of field set. like #third or #second instead of #form1

Comment: yes.. I already did.. but its not working.. It doesn't even hide the fieldset

Comment: post the markup for the page number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hide() function

```
  $('#hide').on('change', function() {
    var hid = $('#hide').val();
    if (hid == "1") {
        $('#second').hide();//Change id of this statement.
        $('#hide option[value="'+hid+'"]').hide();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8mwe5dz/2/

Comment: well, this hides the content but not the Step number on the top. I want to completely remove the whole fieldset..

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use id of field set. like #third or #second instead of #form1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hide').on('change', function() {
        var hid = $('#hide').val();
        if (hid == "1") {
            $('#second').css("display", "none");//Change id of this statement.
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ohh so do you want to remove that element from the select box as well?? is it you want??

Comment: I updated the post.. I want to completely remove that fieldset onchange of the select element. and the page number must be still in order..

Comment: that page number is part of field set or separate one??

Comment: well, I'm using a Jquery Plugin I found in dynamic drive, it's called form to wizard plugin. whenever a new fieldset is added to the form so does the page number..

Comment: :-) I am not sure how that plugin will be working, but here i have few suggestions like. you can give ids to page number dynamically like after loading the page. Suppose your id - second is for fieldset 2 then you can give like secondPage it to page number dynamically. and while removing fieldset you have to remove that page number.